# matlab: correct approach to add geometrical objects to image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

please help with Matlab beginner challenge
i need to create an image with few geometrical objects (circles,
ellipses) and then to apply some projective transforms
my problem is that i cant understand how to actually "draw" on image

image is AFAIU generally  defined as [X;Y;3] matrix,
functions as SCIRCLE1 can compute/return collection of points
representing circle, but the problem is that points are not discrete ,
coordinates are real numbers and not pixels

how can i recompute the scircle output to be valid in image
coordinates system ? i.e. how can i "pixelize" it?

thanks for your attention, i really missing some basic concept and
will appreciate your help

John

Comment: Calm down a little: http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261232

Comment: sorry, i did not expect that matlab newsgroups and stackoverflow are watched  by same community

Comment: The SO community is pretty much in every programming nook and cranny and more so every day.

Answer (score 0):

well, below is an answer i received on Matlab newsgroups
BOTTOM LINE-no built-in way in Matlab

======================================
'getframe' can be used to merge axes even though it is more commonly used to create movie frames.

MATLAB is really weak in this area. There are some primitive
functions for drawing into the overlay (such as rectangle() if you
want to draw a circle, and line() if you want to draw a line) but no
real way that I know of to draw right into the underlying image. So
you have to use "tricks" such as getframe and then apply logical
operations. And you have to be careful with that since I think when
it gives you the rasterized version of the overlay it might be the
size of the image on the screen, not the true original matrix size of
the underlying image (I'd have to recheck this).

full thread here : http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261232

Answer (score 0):

I found this example which give you a easy way to put simple geometrical object onto pictures.

Read the input image.

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
```

Define the rectangle dimensions as `[x y width height]`.

```
rectangle = int32([10 10 30 30]);
```

Draw the rectangle and display the result.

```
J = step(shapeInserter, I, rectangle);
imshow(J);
```

see [this link](http://www.mathworks.se/help/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserterclass.html)

by the way..
I didn't get you point about points not being discrete and images being a matrix. The way I see it. It much the same. you could try to explain it more in depth ?

Answer (score 0):

The [insertShape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox is what you need. It lets you draw rectangles, circles, and polygons into the image.

There is also `insertText`, `insertMarker`, and `insertObjectAnnotation`.